# short nested rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

I have routes such as:

somedomain.com/cities/prague/places/astronomical-clock

```
  resources :cities do
    resources :places
    resources :images
  end
```

I know I can do something like:

```
  match '/:id' => 'cities#show', :as => 'short_city' # /prague
```

but what can I do about having short nested routes?

ie.  /prague/astronomical-clock?

And could/should I make where it overwrites the default url_for methods?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a slight issue differentiating between places and images, but this should work without any controller modification (assuming your above nested routes work)

```
match ':city_id/:id' => 'places#show'
```

**OR**

```
match ':city_id/:id' => 'images#show'
```

to differentiate between then I would recommend

```
match ':city_id/places/:id' => 'places#show'
match ':city_id/images/:id' => 'images#show'
```

**OR** dynamically assign the controller

```
match ':city_id/:controller/:id', :action => :show
```

**RESOURCES**

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Nick's answer but add that if you want to supersede the url_for method you can use :as

```
match '/:id' => 'cities#show', :as => 'city'
match ':city_id/:id' => 'places#show', :as => 'city_place'
```

This way it overwrites the usual city_path url_for methods.